# Create GAE eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I have installed Eclipse Java EE Luna Release (4.4.0) and App Engine SDK 1.9.10
I have created a new Google - Web Application Project and selected the Generate Project Sample Code option. I changed nothing about the project.
The generated project successfully deploys and runs locally. However when I deploy this to AppSpot I get an error message "Remote Procedure Call - Failure" when clicking on the "Send" button on the sample form.
Are there other steps I need to perform in order for the generated project to be successfully deployed to AppSpot?
My goal is to have a starting application that deploys so I can start learning to use Objectify and GWT to build applications. If there is a better way to go about this please suggest it.
Kind regards
Sean

Answer (score 0):

I think seem to remember that sample code for the GWT builds a RPC-based HelloWorld or greeting example. In the auto-generated sample interface you type a name, a RPC call is made to server side and you get "Hello"+yourName or similar as a callback.

Check this link:
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/appengine.html

This is a more advanced app, StockWatcher, from the GWT tutorials which is also RPC based and adapted for the GAE. You could start here: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/gettingstarted.html to build this app (is really easy) and follow to the link above to deploy StockWatcher on the GAE, or check directly the steps on the first link and try to deploy the GWT "Greetings" example.

If you have already tried this or you do and there's still a problem, please provide the full stack trace, or the code you think might be causing the problem, so we have a better insight of the problem.